# Can't create a local branch of already existing github repository in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, github, branch

I have looked up how to create a local branch (and I have done it before), but it won't let me. Please let me know how to fix this problem or if I am missing something.

I am already connected to the github repository, but I am currently using the master branch and I wan't to use a local branch. so I click on VCS --> Git --> Branches and little box titled "Git Branches" pops up with options for "New Branch" and "Checkout Tags and Revision". Usually I would click new branch, but for some reason both options are greyed out.

Am I following the correct steps to make a local branch?

Comment: How did you get to the "master" branch?  Greyed out seems to be telling us that it doesn't want to perform the operation.  Is your working directory dirty?

Comment: I went to VCS --> Checkout From Version Control and selected my repository on github. What do you mean by "Is your working directory dirty"?

Comment: Just check `git status` from the bash.  What does it say?  It may not make sense to switch branches right now.

Comment: I received errors when that happened. I just decided to delete the local project I had and create a clone straight from github again. Now I am able to create a local branch

Comment: OK but this sounds pretty draconian to me.  You should figure out how the Git plugin works, or just drop it and use the command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio 3+, then when you click git on the bottom-right menu and you open it, you have a Seetings button. Then disable the checkbox with the text: Execute branch operations on all roots.